# Javascript code not working with django template

Tags: javascript, html

Good day people, I wrote a javascript code to add a countdown timer to the todo list app I am currently working on but the code is not working and I am not getting any errors. I am a beginner trying to learn on projects but I am currently stuck at this point below are the templates
I will appreciate suggestions on how to solve the problem
BASE.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var options = {'format':'yyyy-mm-dd',}
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems,options);
       
      });
      const whenb=document.getElementById('when')
      console.log(whenb.textContent)
      const countdown=document.getElementById('count_down')
      const date=Date.parse(whenb.textContent)
      setInterval(()=>{
        const now= new Date().getDate()
        const diff=whenb-now
        const d= Math.floor(date/(1000*60*60*24)-now/(1000*60*60*24)) 
        const h=Math.floor((date/(1000*60*60)-now/(1000*60*60))%24)
        const m=Math.floor((date/(1000*60)-now/(1000*60))%60)
        const s=Math.floor((date/(1000)-now/(1000))%60)
        if (diff>0){
        count_down.innerHTML=d+"days,"+" "+h+"hours,"+" "+ m+"minutes,"+" "+s+"seconds left...  "
      }
      },1000)
      </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>todolist</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">To-do-List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
{% block content %} 
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

INDEX.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static%}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="add_todo/" method="post">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input type="text" name="content" >
                <label for="todo" class="add">Add Item</label>
            </div>
           <div class="input-field right" >
                <i class="material-icons prefix">today</i>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" style="display: inline-block; width: 10%; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 218);
                height: 35px;
                width: 60px;
                border-radius:10%;
                margin-top: 30px;
                padding: 5px;">
           </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        {% for items in todo_items %}
        <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item">{{items.item}}
                <div class="right " id="when">Due:{{items.due|date:'d-m-Y'}}</div>
                <div class="right" id="count_down"></div>
                <div class="right">
                    <form action="delete_todo/{{items.id}}/" method="post">
                            
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" style="display: inline-block; width: 10%; background-color: rgb(179, 65, 57);
                        height: 35px;
                        width: 60px;
                        border-radius:10%;
                        margin-top: -7px;
                        padding: 5px;">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
</div>

{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: what do you mean with not working? You got some error in the browserconsole?

Comment: Did you know what `M`is?  In this line: `var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems,options);`

Comment: @Maik I got the following errors in the browser console:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you correct this little mistake:

```js
const diff=whenb-now
```

Needs to be

```js
const diff=date-now
```

Otherwise, you'll try to subtract a date from an HTML element.

Here is an abbreviated example with the corrected code:

```js
const whenb=document.getElementById('when')
      console.log(whenb.textContent)
      const countdown=document.getElementById('count_down')
      const date=Date.parse(whenb.textContent)
      setInterval(()=>{
        const now= new Date().getDate()
        const diff=date-now
        const d=Math.floor(date/(1000*60*60*24)-now/(1000*60*60*24)) 
        const h=Math.floor((date/(1000*60*60)-now/(1000*60*60))%24)
        const m=Math.floor((date/(1000*60)-now/(1000*60))%60)
        const s=Math.floor((date/(1000)-now/(1000))%60)
        if (diff>0){
        count_down.innerHTML=d+"days,"+" "+h+"hours,"+" "+ m+"minutes,"+" "+s+"seconds left...  "
      }
      },1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>todolist</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="when">Sun, 15 May 2022 12:00:00 GMT</div>
  <div id="count_down"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But - depending on the format of your `when` content - there might be a problem with the way you calculate `d`, `h`, `m` and `s`, so the values are not sane. You should have a look at this, but your original problem should be solved.

Btw., you can always use `console.log` to output whatever might be helpful when searching for errors and then view the log using the F12 browser console.